# Multiple Combo Boxes to filter a listbox

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, combobox, listbox

I have a form with 2 combo boxes and 1 listbox. The listbox is populated when I search using a button and a text box. Each combo box independently filters the listbox, but I can not figure out how to get them to layer. i.e. if I have chosen selections in both combo boxes, I would like both of the filters to apply to the listbox.

I would like to do one of the following:
a) Get the filters to layer dynamically based
or
b) Have the filters apply when the search button is clicked

My current layout is:

Combo Boxes: cboJob, cboCompany
ListBox: lstResume
Textbox for searching: txtKeywords
Search Button: btnSearch
data is drawn from qryResume
All data is text

Current Code:

```
Private Sub btnSearch_Click()
Dim SQL As String
SQL = "SELECT qryResume.ID, qryResume.Company, qryResume.Job, qryResume.LastUpdated " _
    & "FROM qryResume " _
    & "Where Company LIKE '*" & Me.txtKeywords & "*' " _
    & " OR Job LIKE '*" & Me.txtKeywords & "*' " _
    & "ORDER BY qryResume.Company "
    Me.lstResume.RowSource = SQL
    Me.lstResume.Requery

End Sub

Private Sub cboCompany_AfterUpdate()
Dim SQL As String
SQL = "SELECT qryResume.ID, qryResume.Company, qryResume.Job, qryResume.LastUpdated " _
    & "FROM qryResume " _
    & "WHERE qryResume.Company = '" & cboCompany.Text & "'" _
    & "ORDER BY qryResume.Company"
    Me.lstResume.RowSource = SQL
    Me.lstResume.Requery

End Sub

Private Sub cboJob_AfterUpdate()
Dim SQL As String
SQL = "SELECT qryResume.ID, qryResume.Company, qryResume.Job, qryResume.LastUpdated " _
    & "FROM qryResume " _
    & "WHERE qryResume.Job = '" & cboJob.Text & "'" _
    & "ORDER BY qryResume.Company"
    Me.lstResume.RowSource = SQL
    Me.lstResume.Requery

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refactor this code pretty easily to the following, if you could use the `.Value` property or `.Column` collection instead of `.Text`:

```
Private Sub RequerylstResume()
   Dim SQL As String
   SQL = "SELECT qryResume.ID, qryResume.Company, qryResume.Job, qryResume.LastUpdated " _
    & "FROM qryResume " _
    & "WHERE 1=1 "
    If cboJob.Value & "" <> "" Then
        SQL = SQL &  " AND qryResume.Job = '" & cboJob.Value & "'"
    End If
    If cboCompany.Value & "" <> "" Then
        SQL = SQL & " AND qryResume.Company = '" & cboCompany.Value & "'"
    End If
    If Me.TextKeyWords.Value & "" <> "" Then 
        SQL = SQL & " AND (Company LIKE '*" & Me.txtKeywords & "*' " _
        & " OR Job LIKE '*" & Me.txtKeywords.Value & "*') "
    End If
    SQL = SQL & " ORDER BY qryResume.Company" 
    Me.lstResume.RowSource = SQL
    Me.lstResume.Requery
End Sub
```

Then, whenever you want to execute a search, just call `RequerylstResume`.

You call a sub like this:

```
Private Sub cboJob_AfterUpdate()
    RequerylstResume
End Sub
```

And put the sub you want to call in the same module, outside of any other sub

Comment: I am sorry, I am a little new to Access, how do I call the requery? Where do I put that code? In the button click area? Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Anywhere you want. I'd put it in all sections you've previously had code (after update on the combo boxes and the search box). But that depends on your preference, you might just want it on the search button.

Comment: Any chance you could show me exactly how it would look if I attached it to the button? Thank you!

Comment: I keep getting a Compile error: Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment

Comment: I've made some minor changes. Please be specific: where do you get that error (which line, when doing what)?

Comment: Error on: Private Sub CboCompany_AfterUpdate()    when I click on the button

Comment: Please share that code. I haven't included it in my answer. The button should be unrelated to an after update event...

Comment: Private Sub cboCompany_AfterUpdate()
Private Sub RequerylstResume()
   Dim SQL As String      (then rest of code provided above) I just am having trouble understanding where the above code would go or if it would just supplant my old code? - also I said button before but meant combobox, sorry! Thank you for all your help!